# Azure ARM Template - is it possible to get existing resources names to specify them as parameters or variables inside new ARM deployment?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

My issue is related to Azure ARM

I want to populate the parameters allowed list with values, taken from the current resource group.
To be clear - I want to place a virtual machine to virtual network subnet, but I don't want to enter vNet name manually. I already have  find a way to get resourcegroup id, resource group name, subscription id but it seems what there is no way to get a list of objects from here - only if I know resource name, please tell me - it is possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible at all with ARM Templates. What you can do - you can use powershell script that would pull those values and the user will pick one of those values before the deployment (using `Out-GridView`, for example).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is of cource a little dissapointing me. unfortunately my repo is not enough to vote for your answer.